# C# WindowsCE.Forms InputPanel (SIP) : How to make the enter key to dispose the the panel?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am trying to make the textbox's GotFocus event to pop-up WindowsCE.Forms InputPanel.
The system will be running on PDA, so I needed SIP.
I made LostFocus event to dispose (close) the panel, but I also want to make the enter key to close the panel as a sign of "done".
I looked up MSDN and many other tutorial on the web, but I couldn't find any useful help.

Could anyone help me on this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's SIP refer to in your question? The SIP tag you've used refers to Session Initiation Protocol RFC3261.

Comment: SIP == Soft Input Panel (or software keyboard).  If you do CE development, you're fmiliar with it.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own SIP. The Windows CE Input Panel is way too small. Nevertheless ctacke answer is correct as i know.

Comment: Software-based Input Panel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932590.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to true, add a handler for the Enter key and call `this.Close()` when you see it.